# Can't understanding function's return and echo behaviour

Tags: php

Why this echoing `Hello Hello World World` instead of `Hello World Hello World`

```
function a(){
    echo "Hello ";
    return "World ";
}
echo a().a();
```

Output:

```
Hello Hello World World
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the function will `echo` twice before the string `a().a()` had been evaluated. The instruction `echo a().a()` says, run function `a()` twice, concatenate the output and `echo` the output. While concatenating the string to `echo`, the instruction `echo "Hello "` already ran twice. This is alike resolving math formulas, there are rules in which order the functions will execute.

Answer (score 0):

Return function return value to calling function. while echo print the output when it is called.
I have modified a code to present the testcase.

```
<?php

function a(){
    echo "Hello";
    return "World";
}
echo a();
echo a();
?>
```

output is like this

> HelloWorldHelloWorld

In this case calling function return to main function control and print 'Hello World'. Then call the second call for a() function.

> For your code. You are calling like this `a().a()`. In this case calling function returns value to location where it calls. In your case it returned value to `a()` then execute its body. After last return, controls came to main block code. Then echo the 'world'.

I hope this makes sense. Thanks